# Find Basis for kernel and image from homomorphism

Tags: vector-spaces

I have the homomorphism $\varphi(X)=AXA, X\in V=\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ where $A=\left( {\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)$

My task is to calculate an basis from $ker(\varphi)$ and from $img(\varphi)$.

However I don't know how I can do this. Can you give me a tip please? I read on the internet how to calculate an basis from kernel of a matrix, but I don't have a matrix rather than an homomorphism. Maybe it would help me already, if you could tell me that $ker(\varphi)$ and $img(\varphi)$ would look like...

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

The matrix $AXA$ should be $L=\left( {\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ b+d & b+d \\
  \end{array} } \right)$

Now I tried to calculate $L=0$. Therefore I made some cases and got the following result:

$b+d\neq0$ then $(b+d)x+(b+d)y=0, x=-y, y=y$

$a+d=0$ then $x=x, y=y$

Is this right and how does it help me?

Comment: Write $X=(x_{ij})$ and compute $AXA$. Then rewrite $AXA=0$ in terms of the variables $x_{ij}$.

Comment: @amd sry, typo. Corrected it!

Comment: If $a+c=0$, then $(b+d)/(a+c)$ is undefined!

Comment: Go back and check your matrix multiplication. Right-multiplying $X$ by $(0,1)^T$ picks out its second column, so $a$ and $c$ should not appear anywhere in $AXA$.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking people to tell you requires the following steps, which you should do yourself.

1. Write down the matrix $X$ in terms of, say, the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$.
2. Carry out the multiplication $AXA$. Express the result in terms of $a,b,c,d$.
3. Figure out what does it mean for $AXA$ to be zero in terms of $a,b,c,d$.
4. Deduce from 3. the kernel of $\varphi$.
5. Find a basis for the kernel you found in 4.
6. Go back to 2, identify the image.
7. Find a basis for the image.

Comment: Hi, the question is slightly weird, the gentleman is asking to find a basis from the kernel.

Comment: The gentleman is not a native English speaker, obviously.

Comment: Right, fair enough.

Comment: Or maybe the gentleman is, and he got "from" and "for" mixed by mistake.

Comment: sry, I mean "for". I'll edit it!

Comment: @uniquesolution I updated the question and tried to go over your steps. However I stock at step 4, beacuse I have three cases and can't find a way out...

Comment: @locovog -- Sorry, it is 10:25 p.m where I am at, and I am done doing other people's homework for the day. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: ok, no problem :)